# Resizing window in same dimension(16:9) JAVA JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, 2d-games

I am coding a 2D platformer in java/javafx, and I want to make the game resizable. But to not make 32x32px blocks look like if they're dragged out in an axis, I have to make the `JFrame` stay in the same dimension(16:9) all the time, so you can't expand or shrink the `JFrame` without affecting both `x` and `y`.

Also, I wondered how to make a game able to enter full screen mode when you press F11.

Thanks!

Comment: *"Also, I wondered.."* Each problem should be handled on a separate question thread. This works best for people either asking or answering questions, or for people looking for solutions later.

Comment: *" have to make the JFrame stay in the same dimension(16:9) all the time"* - This is actually extremely difficult and general introduces a number of other issues. A better solution is to maintain the content in a 16:9 ratio based on the available frame size